# AMpscript (SFMC) giving error : An IF statement is not closed with the required ENDIF statement

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, sfmc-business-unit

I am showing a description based on the value of points

```
%%[ var @firstname,@memberid , @points , @desc

Set @firstname = [FirstName]
Set @memberid = [MemberId]
Set @points = [Points]

%%[ If @points > 150 Then ]%%
Set @desc = 'you are a platinum customer'
%%[elseif @points > 100 ]%%
Set @desc = 'You are a gold customer'
%%[elseif @points > 50 ]%%
set @desc = 'You are a silver customer'
%%[elseif  ]%%
set @desc = 'You are an insider customer'
%%[ENDIF ]%%

]%%
```

Dear `%%=v(@firstname)=%%` , Your  Member ID : `%%=v(@memberid)=%%`  .
Based upon your points `%%=v(@desc)=%%`

**I am getting an error: An IF/ELSEIF statement is invalid. No terminating THEN for the statement is found.**
Please Help !

Answer (score 1):

Once you open a AMPscript block with `%%[` you shouldn't have another open block till you close it, so your AMPscript should be something more like

```
%%[ var @firstname,@memberid , @points , @desc

Set @firstname = [FirstName]
Set @memberid = [MemberId]
Set @points = [Points]

If @points > 150 Then 
Set @desc = 'you are a platinum customer'
elseif @points > 100 THEN
Set @desc = 'You are a gold customer'
elseif @points > 50 THEN
set @desc = 'You are a silver customer'
else  
set @desc = 'You are an insider customer'
ENDIF ]%%
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for responding! I tried that code and I am getting this error: An IF/ELSEIF statement is invalid. No terminating THEN for the statement is found.

Comment: Do what EazyE wrote, but add a `THEN` at the end of each line starting with `ELSEIF`.  Also, consider making the last `ELSEIF` an `ELSE` - in this case with no `THEN`. As can be seen in the docs here - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/languageElements.html

Comment: Updated code with @JonasLamberty suggestions :)

Comment: Guys it worked out with the changes !! Thanks :)